# Errror: solr update index on product

Tags: solr

I have a solr server and try to update index from website. I copied the settings files from another working core with same schema and modified in data-config new connection settings. But when I run update on single product on website server I get "Communication error" (the full index import works). The settings for the old index that I copied from, works on same website server. Can you help me?

If you need clarification please ask.

Comment: That seems to be a configuration error on the website and possibly depending on how it works. You'll have to provide more details, and check the log for your website.

Comment: I created a file and called the index product function and it works. When I include this file in prestashop it works. But when I include direct the solr class it gives the Communication error. I believe It is some conflict. I will check more. Thank you Mats